# Extracting Dialog Box Text in iMacros or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I am using iMacros 7.6.0.2 I am trying to figure how to extract text from a pop up dialog box (not one that I have created). I am using JavaScript, and SET !EXTRACTDIALOG YES doesn't work with my version of iMacros.. Upgrading isn't an option so I am wondering if there is any way to do this or if I am screwed...Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you put a screen shot of the dialog you want to extract?

Comment: Hello @IceD I have attached a photo Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction

Check out the link above and there are few examples.

```
URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/demo/v6/dialogs/javascript2.htm
SET !EXTRACTDIALOG YES
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=VALUE:Popup<SP>1
WAIT SECONDS=3
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Here is one example. Also there is folder Demo-FireFox in iMacros folder. It has examples of iMacros scripts. There are few exatract examples and of them could help you.

Comment: I have tried this, like I said SET !EXTRACTDIALOG YES doesn't work with my version. I have read through the wiki but I will double check to see if there is anything else that will help me thanks @IceD.