# How can I extract dialog text using javascript and iMacro on firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, imacros, browser-automation

I am in big problem. I have to update person information from a csv file. But I also need to save status when the person Id was searched. It can be already updated, incorrect or may open a per populated form.

I need to extract that dialog text and save in a status.csv file. If no error occured then I can update the form and submit it, and again the text in the last dialog can be extracted and saved in a status.csv file.

**Is there any solution for extracting dialog text with iMacro and js on Firefox. The solution link given on the iMacro wiki didn't work for me.**

This question is not useful: [not a solution for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744139/extracting-dialog-box-text-in-imacros-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this solution would work for you:

```
// imitation of javascript dialog
var ret = iimPlayCode('URL GOTO=javascript:{alert("Dialog<SP>text<SP>to<SP>be<SP>extracted");}')

// extracting dialog text
if (ret < 0) 
    var dlgText = iimGetErrorText();
dlgText = dlgText.match(/Dialog message: "(.*)",/)[1];
```

Comment: my dialog text can be anything from 2-3 status messages. It can for error, success and next step.

Comment: If the dialog is a jQuery control (but not a JavaScript one as I supposed in my answer), you can also extract the dialog text handling it as DOM element. In this case an html-code is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by “this code”: my answer or the previous note as to jQuery control? Write what dialog you’ve got indeed.